# Open google.com using localhost:port combination

Tags: networking

I have a computer running Ubuntu that has access to a certain website over VPN which no other computer on the LAN does. I am trying to access this computer via another computer on the same LAN network.

One solution that comes to mind is mapping the website address to the ip:random_port combination for it to act as server for the other computers on the LAN. But I do not know how to accomplish this.

I would appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `ssh` socks proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with SSH feature of remote port forwarding: `ssh -R <site_address>:<site_port>:localhost:<local_port> <VPN_host_address>` this will cause, than any invocation to `localhost:<local_port>` will lead you over `<VPN_host_address>` to `<site_address>:<site_port>`.